# OpenCV (Python) Drawing on Videos, Tracking

Tags: python, opencv, drawing

```
# libraries that will be needed
import numpy as np  # numpy
import cv2          # opencv
import imutils      # allows video editing
import random       
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
from imutils import paths
import imutils
import cv2

#default HOG
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())


# function to trak people
def tracker(cap):
    while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()

    # if video stopped playing, quit
    if ret == False:
        break

        # resize window
        img = imutils.resize(img, width = 400)
        # convert to graysclae and equalize
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)

        # detect people
        rects, weights = hog.detectMultiScale(gray, winStride = (8, 8), padding = (8, 8), scale = 1.25)
        # store detected people in array
        rects = np.array([[x, y, x+w, y+h] for(x, y, w, h) in rects] )
        # find largest possible rectangel to avoid detection
        # of same person several times
        biggest = non_max_suppression(rects, probs = None, overlapThresh = 0.65)

        # draw largest rectangle
        for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in biggest:
            # create random color
            color = (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))
            cv2.rectangle(img, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), color, 2)        

        # show image
        cv2.imshow('Image', img)

        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
# run video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('NYC.mp4')
tracker(cap)
# release frame and destroy windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

I am attempting to track multiple people at once using OpenCV. Once a person is detected, I draw a rectangle around them. I am having trouble having a random/different color box for each person while maintaining the same color box for a person after they have been detected.

Currently, a person is detected and a box is drawn. In the next frame, if they are still detected a new colored box is drawn, but I would like to maintain the original color.

Also open to tips/tricks that will improve my code and tracking since I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to say with good confidence this is the person in the next frame if you want to draw same color box for the same person. There are many ways to do it. 
One way is you can use tracking. Try using Camshift/meanshift tracking(ofcourse there are many tracking algo, I wont be sure which one suits you best since i dont know your dataset).

Once a person is detected, initialise a tracker and assign a color box to that person. If person is out of the image, then have a system to remove the person from the list.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Would I be able to do this based upon the "rects" value that is returned by hog.detectMultiScale? Also, would altering the location of the random color be beneficial?

Answer (score 0):

Your `if ret == False:` is not indented correctly to match the `while True:` loop. Current Code:

```
def tracker(cap):
    while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()

    # if video stopped playing, quit
    if ret == False:
        break

        # resize window
        img = imutils.resize(img, width = 400)
        # convert to graysclae and equalize
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
```

Fixed indentation:

```
def tracker(cap):
    while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()

        # if video stopped playing, quit
        if ret == False:
            break

        # resize window
        img = imutils.resize(img, width = 400)
        # convert to graysclae and equalize
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
```